# Checking if a cell contains a specific value MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a more efficient way to reproduce these results?

```
store = {'1','2','3','4','5'};

for jj = 1:5
correct(jj) = isequal(store{jj}, '3');
end
```

This is a for loop in matlab...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%%
store = {'1','2','3','4','5'};

for jj = 1:5
correct(jj) = isequal(store{jj}, '3');
end
%%
(strcmp(store,'3'))
```

strcmp will solve your problem

Comment: Note that the `isequal` approach and the `strcmp` approach would give _different results_ for `store = {'1','2',51,'4','5'};` (`51` is the ASCII code of `'5'`)